# SVN keyword is shown in doxygen

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, doxygen

I am using svn keywords ($Author$, ...) in my project. I am also using doxygen comments to improve my documentation. The combination of both are causing some trouble for me. 
Simplified example:

```
/**
*   @author     $Author$
*/
```

@author is the doxygen keyword and $Author$ is the svn keyword. My doxygen-html-output looks like this: 
[image]

How can I do this properly? I don't want to see the svn-keywords in my doxygen documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in the past is I have a versioned template doxygen (doxy.in) file which contain this:

```
/**
*   @author     $Author$
*/
```

When I go to build my documentation (`make doc`), my script first calls SubWCRev to replace all instances of those keywords with SVN keywords.  I use this to produce an unversioned doxygen file `doxy.out` which I then pass into doxygen to produce my documentation.

Comment: I noticed you haven't selected an answer yet.  If it helps I've recently written a good answer to a similar question using Cmake [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209705/how-to-version-control-out-of-source-build-directory-using-cmake-and-svn/45198417#45198417).  The function referenced uses the output of `svn info` to embed info into source code.

Answer (score 1):

SVN keywords always expand in a fashion that makes it clear that the particular string is an expanded keyword and not a "regular" line. In other words, expanded keywords will always include dollar signs and the name of the keyword. One of the reasons for this is to avoid confusion between automated keyword-generated content and non-generated one.

However, you should be able to configure Doxygen to reformat the line that contains the expanded keyword. For example, configure it to look for `$Author: CONTENT $` in a line and reformat it as you wish in HTML output.